# Oracle Apex 5 Region/item refresh after error

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Is there a way to refresh a region or item (clear the cache) after an error happens. I have a tabular form that selects from a table that has unique constraints on a few columns. When trying to make a duplicate entry Oracle Apex throws a unique constraint error, clears the row(the row is still visible, but empty)that made the error, but does not clear the cache of the tabular form (the data that used to be there is still saved somewhere). If the user then tries to enter data in other columns of that row in a way that it doesn't break the constraints...the row will get inserted including the data that originally broke the constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create dynamic action on page load where your event will refresh tabular region. Your tabular form now will be refreshed.